# Setting value and clicking a submit button with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have a test that unfortunately reveals some serious misunderstanding on my part on how to test this React web application using react-testing-library. The test:

```
const setup = () => {
    const utils = render(<UnderConstruction />)
    const input = utils.getByLabelText('Email')
    return {
        input,
        ...utils,
    }
}

test('It should set the email input', () => {
    const { input } = setup();
    const element = input as HTMLInputElement;
    fireEvent.change(element, { target: { value: 'abc@def' } });
    console.log(element.value);
    expect(element.value).toBe('abc@def');
})
```

The simple component (uses marterial-ui) looks like (I have removed large portions of it for brevity):

```
<form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <TextField
        id="email-notification"
        name="email-notification"
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onInput={(e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>) => {
            let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
            setEmail(target.value);
        }}
        placeholder="Email" />
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <Button
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
    >
        Submit
    </Button>
</form>
```

First the as cast is to keep TypeScript happy. Second is mainly around my use of fireEvent to simulate a user input. Any ideas on how I can test this functionality? Righ now the test aways fails as it is expecting abc@def and receiving ''.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `TextField` component of MUI Component, so you can not get real input with `getByLabelText`. Instead of that, you should use `getByPlaceholderText`.
Try this:

```js
const setup = () => {
    const utils = render(<UnderConstruction />)
    const input = utils.getByPlaceholderText('Email')
    return {
        input,
        ...utils,
    }
}

test('It should set the email input', () => {
    const { input } = setup();
    const element = input as HTMLInputElement;
    fireEvent.change(element, { target: { value: 'abc@def' } });
    console.log(element.value);
    expect(element.value).toBe('abc@def');
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. That did not work for me either.

Comment: I ran a test taking material-ui out of the picture and I found that if I  initialize the input ( via the value attribute/property - `value="xxx"` ) then I get the same behavior as with the material-ui TextField. However if I leave this attribute/property off then I get the expected behavior - the input value is changed. Any ideas on how to compensate for the initial value?

Comment: @KevinBurton What is the initial value of  ```email``` in the ```TextField```?

Answer (score 0):

Using UI library like this, if getByLabelText or getByPlaceholderText don't work, I usually get the underlying input element this way:

```
// add a data-testid="myElement" on the TextField component

// in test:
fireEvent.change(getByTestId('myElement').querySelector('input'), { target: { value: 'abc@def' } });
```

This is not ideal though, getByLabelText or getByPlaceholderText should be used when possible.